# Converting Automator Action in applescript to bash script

Tags: applescript, automator, bash, ftp

I just wrote an Automator app using AppleScript (along with a couple of bash lines) to start FTP with a single click. However it runs more than a tad slow. Here's the code:

```
set ftpstatus to "off"
try
    do shell script "echo \"QUIT\" | telnet 127.0.0.1" & " ftp 2>&1 | grep  \"Escape character is\" > /dev/null"
    set ftpstatus to "on"
on error
    set ftpstatus to "off"
end try
if (ftpstatus = "off") then
    set ipaddr to IPv4 address of (get system info)
    set sun to short user name of (get system info)
    do shell script "sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist" with administrator privileges
    tell application "Finder" to display alert "FTP Launched and ready for file-transfer" & character id 8233 & character id 8233 & character id 8233 & "Address: ftp://" & ipaddr & ":21" & character id 8233 & "User Name: " & sun
else
    do shell script "sudo -s launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist" with administrator privileges
    tell application "Finder" to display alert "FTP session closed"
end if
```

Here's what the code does:

1. Check if FTP server is running
2. If yes, turn it off and throw a message box saying "FTP session closed"
3. If no, turn it on and throw a message box saying "FTP session open" along with my IP address and username

This script works like charm but since it's too slow, I am wondering if there's any way to convert it to a bash shell script. That should speed up things a lot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly - if in the third line of Your script You're checking whether `ftp` service is running You can use following script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                   

launchctl list | grep ftpd

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    IPADDR=$(ifconfig -a | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1' | grep -v 127.0.0.1)
    launchctl load "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist"
    osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to display alert \"FTP Launched and ready for file-transfer\" & character id 8233 & character id 8233 & character id 8233 & \"Address: ftp://\" & \"$IPADDR\" & \":21\" & character id 8233 & \"User Name: \" & \"$USER\""
else
    launchctl unload -w "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist"
    osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to display alert "FTP session closed"'
fi
```

Run this a `sudo`.
Explanation:

- To check if job is running use `launchctl list`.
- To get ip address quickly use my perl script (You may want to `grep` it differently in order to get rid of additional IP addresses.
- The only problem now is that **Finder** app is not brought to front but this can be solved if needed.

Comment: The assignment to IPADDR assumes that there is only *one* active network interface besides `localhost`

Comment: @patrix that is correct. I've mentioned about that in my answer. To get one specific interface IP script would need to be changed.

Comment: Upps, right, didn't notice that

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek thanks for the detailed answer. But won't this launch in Terminal even if I compiled it as a UNIX executable because of the sudo? Is there any way to make the program Terminal-independent?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia You may insert this script to AppleScript editor, add line like: `do shell script ... with administrator privileges` You'll be prompted to input Your password. Another way is to make an application which will launch Your script with `sudo`. Generally executables properly enclosed inside *.app bundle does not have to launch Terminal.

Comment: Well, honestly, I already have the Automator script but the whole point i was looking for a bash translation was to not have to use Automator to run the program. I was looking for something like a standalone app with all the required privileges or maybe a popup but without the automator or terminal running in the background

Comment: So it's a bit risky to let apps do the work with elevated privilages. However I can help You compile ObjC application to launch bashscript. We may try to ask for passowrd with a prompt, or something with setuid/setgid. Here are some informations about differences: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/securecodingguide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW3